# Jpa repository with list of enum

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

So I want to implement a Jpa Repository of my class Reservation.

My RoomType Enum:

```
public enum RoomType{
    BREUGHELZAAL("Breughel zaal"),
    CARDIJNZAAL("Cardijn zaal"),
    FEESTZAAL("Feest zaal"),
    KEUKEN("Keuken"),
    RECEPTIEZAAL("Receptie zaal"),
    KLEINEKEUKEN("Kleine keuken");

    private String roomType;

    RoomType(String roomType){
       this.roomType= roomType;
    }

    public String getRoomType(){
        return roomType;
    }
}
```

Now I have no clue how to implement this. I need a List of Enum types in my reservation class, i guess it is something like this, but I don't know the annotation for the enum type:

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
List<RoomType> chosenRooms
```

Thanks in advance for the help!!

Comment: Wouldn't the RoomType be a candidate for making it an entity instead of an enum, anyway?

Comment: The roomtypes don't change. There are 6 room types and they never change. So I don't know if making this an entity, is the right solution

Comment: Never say never :D. Of course, you know your context best, but an entity is more flexible and probably future-proof. Even when the types don't change, maybe you'd like to store the size or the capacity of a _zaal_, too. Just brainstorming...

Comment: You're right, I could do it like an entity. I'm considering to store the RoomType as a list of entities... I'm not confident that all these annotations do the optimal job :-)

Comment: Btw _zaal_ is dutch for Room xD

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't have sufficient config for Enum persistence, try :

```
@ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@CollectionTable(name = "RoomType", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "id"))
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
List<RoomType> chosenRooms
```

`@ElementCollection` - Defines a collection of instances of a basic type or embeddable class.
`@CollectionTable` - pecifies the table that is used for the mapping of collections of basic or embeddable types (`name` - name of the collection table, `joinColumn` - The foreign key columns of the collection table).
`Enumerated` - Specifies that a persistent property or field should be persisted as a enumerated type.

Comment: Can you explain what these annotation configure? I would like to know for in the future. I works, but I would like to know why :)